# Matlab R2016b vs R2014b: Multiplication/power of arrays

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab code written on R2016b platform, which I am running now on R2014b.

Part of code involves a operation of vectors `a` and `b`. The size of `a` is `(7,1)` and `b` is `(1,8)`. The operation `a^b` works and returns `(7,8)` matrix in `R2016b`, whereas it fails in `R2014b`. How to work around this issue for `R2014b`?

Comment: Did you mean `a.^b`?

Answer (score 3):

You may use [bsxfun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) as follows:

```
c = bsxfun(@power, a, b);
```

---

`bsxfun` description:

> Apply element-wise operation to two arrays with implicit expansion enabled